# Comparing C pointers in Python

Tags: python, c, pointers, ffi, cffi

I am looking for an easier way to compare the data at two C-pointers in python. The method I have working now:

```
import cffi

ffi = cffi.FFI()

def ref_char_p(char_p):
    arr = []
    null_term = 0;
    while(char_p[null_term] != 0):
        null_term += 1

    for x in range(0, null_term):
        arr.append(char_p[x])
    return arr

char_p = ffi.new("char[]", '\x41\x42\x43')
char_p2 = ffi.new("char[]", '\x41\x42\x43')

if(ref_char_p(char_p) == ref_char_p(char_p2)):
    print "equal"
else:
    print "not equal"
```

Is there any way I can do something closer to:

```
if(char_p == char_p2):
    print "equal"
```

I have read through the cffi docs but have not found anything promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ffi.string()` to convert the char array to a bytes object:

```
ffi.string(char_p) == ffi.string(char_p2)
```

Comment: Amazing. Just what I was looking for. Thank you!